# Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens'

Tags: php, mysql

I have a Query that populates `$row["app_id"]` and as I go through my `div id="reveal"` that `app_id` changes. What I'm trying to do is plug that app_id in the $revealstmt query. I keep receiving error.

```
 Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid     
 parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens
```

My code is as follows

```
    <?php   
    $revealid = $row["app_id"];
    while (isset($revealid)){
            $query3 = "";
            $revealstmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT logs.time_entry AS logs_entry, logs.description AS logs_description, substates.name AS reveal_substates_name FROM logs LEFT OUTER JOIN applications ON logs.fk_app_id = applications.pk_app_id LEFT OUTER JOIN substates ON logs.fk_substate_id = substates.pk_substate_id WHERE logs.fk_app_id = <?php echo $revealid ?> and time_entry >= curdate() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(curdate()) + 14 DAY ORDER BY time_entry DESC;");
            $revealstmt->execute(array('query3' => $query3));
 ?>

 <div id="<?php echo $row["app_name"];?>" class='reveal-modal'>
    <div id="reveal"> 
            <h1><?php echo $row["app_name"]; echo $revealid; ?>
            <br />
            </h1>
            <div class="accordion">
                    <?php while ($revealrow = $revealstmt->fetch()){?>
                            <h3><a href=""><?php echo $revealrow["logs_entry"]?> -|- <? 
 php echo $revealrow["reveal_substates_name"]; ?></a></h3>
                            <div><?php echo $revealrow["logs_description"]; ?></div>
                    <?php  }  ?> <!-- Close Tag for $revealrow -->
    <?php } ?> <!-- Close tag for the while(isset) -->
```

I've tried using foreach but cannot as `$row["app_id"]` isn't an array it only returns 1 number at a time.

Hopefully I've given all the information needed, if not will of course add whatever I need to. Thanks again to the community for all of your help!

Comment: Where does `query3` appear in your SQL query?  Also, I think your placeholders need to start with `:`.

Comment: What is that `<?php echo $revealid ?>` doing inside the query? You're already in PHP, you cannot just do that. Use concatenation instead.

Comment: I'm more than likely wrong as I'm obviously learning. I thought query3 was the array returned from the SQL Query. Also I'll check on the concatenation. I didn't realize you could do that in the middle of a SQL Query I thought you had to go back into php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use concatenation instead in your query. Besides, you don't want queries that long. In the same way you wouldn't write all your PHP in one line, the same goes for your MySQL: it's another language.

```
$revealstmt = $conn->prepare(
  "SELECT logs.time_entry AS logs_entry, " . 
    "logs.description AS logs_description, " .
    "substates.name AS reveal_substates_name " . 
  "FROM logs LEFT OUTER JOIN applications " .
  "ON logs.fk_app_id = applications.pk_app_id " . 
  "LEFT OUTER JOIN substates ON logs.fk_substate_id = substates.pk_substate_id " .
  "WHERE logs.fk_app_id = " . $revealid . " AND " .
  "time_entry >= curdate() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(curdate()) + 14 DAY " .
  "ORDER BY time_entry DESC;");
$revealstmt->execute();
```

Another problem is that you were trying to assign `query3` to something. There was no `?` placeholder in your query, thus, no need to add anything in your `execute()`. However, the other working solution can be not secure depending on where your `$revealid` comes from. You can make it secure by doing this:

```
$revealstmt = $conn->prepare(
  "SELECT logs.time_entry AS logs_entry, " . 
    "logs.description AS logs_description, " .
    "substates.name AS reveal_substates_name " . 
  "FROM logs LEFT OUTER JOIN applications " .
  "ON logs.fk_app_id = applications.pk_app_id " . 
  "LEFT OUTER JOIN substates ON logs.fk_substate_id = substates.pk_substate_id " .
  "WHERE logs.fk_app_id = ? AND " .
  "time_entry >= curdate() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(curdate()) + 14 DAY " .
  "ORDER BY time_entry DESC;");
$revealstmt->execute(array($revealid));
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm just now starting to do a lot of SQL as I'm sure you can tell but this is definitely something I'll start to work on. Typically when I'm making my queries in Workbench I have them like you do but when I put them in my code I put it all on one line. Thanks again for the help!

Answer (score 2):

I believe your query prepare statement has the wrong syntax. Try this:

```
$revealstmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT logs.time_entry AS logs_entry, logs.description AS   logs_description, substates.name AS reveal_substates_name FROM logs LEFT OUTER JOIN applications ON logs.fk_app_id = applications.pk_app_id LEFT OUTER JOIN substates ON logs.fk_substate_id = substates.pk_substate_id WHERE logs.fk_app_id = ".$revealid." and time_entry >= curdate() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(curdate()) + 14 DAY ORDER BY time_entry DESC;");
```

If you echo the value it should go to stdout and not to the string/query you are preparing.

Comment: Thank you so much!! I've been working on this for almost 2 days and had no idea I was shooting myself in the foot with just that being there. THANK YOU everyone who contributed SO MUCH!

Comment: -1, while this answers the OP question, it has a flawed security and it's really easy to attack with an `sql injection`.

Comment: @FranciscoPresencia you are absolutely right! Had no time to point this out as well...

Answer (score 0):

`$revealstmt->execute(array('query3' => $query3));` this is your problem, your query have no binding values but still you are sending an array of bindings on your `execute statment`.

Try this one:

```
$revealstmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT logs.time_entry AS logs_entry, logs.description AS   logs_description, substates.name AS reveal_substates_name FROM logs LEFT OUTER JOIN applications ON logs.fk_app_id = applications.pk_app_id LEFT OUTER JOIN substates ON logs.fk_substate_id = substates.pk_substate_id WHERE logs.fk_app_id = :query3 and time_entry >= curdate() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(curdate()) + 14 DAY ORDER BY time_entry DESC;");
```

and then you execute yout query by passing the binding values like so:

`$revealstmt->execute(array('query3' => $revealid));`

OR :

`$revealstmt->bindValue(':query3', $revealid);`